# Different pictogram for folders in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have in eclipse a linked directory, but I somehow have two types of directory pictograms that function in exactly the same way. The options are the same too, but the pictograms are different. Here is the image:

[image] http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg832/scaled.php?server=832&filename=testbn.png&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg832/scaled.php?server=832&filename=testbn.png&res=landing)

Layout descriptor has a different icon than the other folders.
Why are the pictograms different? Is there any difference in their functionality? How can I change them to the appropriate pictogram?

Comment: May be because layout.. is a simple folder which may contains images/other resources stuff where data, fonts etc.. is a package in which your source code will be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) explains what the Eclipse JDT icons mean.

In your example:

- `data` and `skin` are packages that only contain non-Java files.
- `fonts` is an empty package.
- `layout-descriptors` is a folder.

The reason that `layout-descriptors` shows up differently than the other three is because it is an invalid Java package name (contains a dash).

Comment: Thank you! I also assume that there is no relevant difference between a "logical package" and a "folder" because when I add a new folder to the asset directory a package is added instead.

Comment: Yeah, in the filesystem, packages are just folders.